# Humble tutorial creating a workspace

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just started my journey to learn ROS2 and worked through the humble tutorial (I am using Ubuntu 22.04.). I tried to follow the instruction [to create a workspace](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html) and everything worked fine until step 5 where this error occured.

```
[0.392s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
        'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
    If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.
    
    If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
        --allow-overriding turtlesim
    
    This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
    Starting >>> turtlesim
    --- stderr: turtlesim                               
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
        from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
    ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py' from 'rosidl_generator_py' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/__init__.py)
    gmake[2]: *** [turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/build.make:121: rosidl_generator_py/turtlesim/_turtlesim_s.ep.rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.c] Error 1
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/all] Error 2
    gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
    ---
    Failed   <<< turtlesim [25.5s, exited with code 2]
                                     
    Summary: 0 packages finished [25.7s]
      1 package failed: turtlesim
      1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
```

In one [post](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/465) I read, it was suggested not to source before creating a workspace, however this didn't help and I got this error. Where I noticed the issue with the "rosidl_generator_py" module.

```
Starting >>> turtlesim
--- stderr: turtlesim                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
    from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosidl_generator_py'
gmake[2]: *** [turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/build.make:121: rosidl_generator_py/turtlesim/_turtlesim_s.ep.rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.c] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< turtlesim [0.37s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.47s]
  1 package failed: turtlesim
  1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
```

After reading another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752937/ros2-importerror-cannot-import-name-generate-py-from-rosidl-generator-py), it was possible to create a workspace as I commented the required package "rosidl_default_generators" in the CMakeLists.txt file. However, I would like to know if there is a better way to fix this problem.

```
[0.358s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
    'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/humble
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding turtlesim

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> turtlesim
Finished <<< turtlesim [1.62s]                     

Summary: 1 package finished [1.77s]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407879/humble-tutorial-creating-a-workspace/) by [j-sohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/120382/j-sohn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-10-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-14**:
Are you using environments like `conda` etc? I followed the tutorial and face no issues. Can you please execute the following command and share the output: `printenv | grep PYTHONPATH`

**Comment by [j-sohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/120382/j-sohn/) on 2022-10-14**:
Thanks for the hint! Yes, I use anaconda.
I deactivated the environment through `conda deactivate` and it solved the problem. Everything works fine now! Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-15**:
Glad you made it work!

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-15**:
@ravijoshi You comment was a very nice intuition.

**Comment by [iwasinnam](https://answers.ros.org/users/135060/iwasinnam/) on 2023-01-22**:
I don't have conda so this solution didn't work for me. But commenting out rosidl_default_generators did work, and it's good enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the answer is solved with this

```
conda deactivate
```

Then close the question

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2022-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-19**:
@duck-development Normally we don't "close" questions on this site unless there is a problem with it, for example if it is off-topic or a duplicate.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2022-10-19**:
It was for @j-sohn. And I mean mark the question as answered. So other see how to sove this kind of question